# How to automatically update month and year in title

Tags: wordpress

As tittle, could you please help me how to automatically update month and year in title and meta description in a post, a taxonomy post?
Thanks so much.

Comment: Could you please provide a little more information or an example of what you're wanting to achieve?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you already tried yourself to do this? Please review [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Stack Overflow is not a coding service. You are expected to ***research your issue and make a good attempt to write the code yourself*** before posting. If you then get stuck on something *specific*, come back and include a summary of what you tried and a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use date of created/updated post, you can easily do this with wordpress function:

```
<?php echo get_the_date($format, get_the_ID()); ?>
```

So in title looks like this:

```
<title><?php echo get_the_date('j.n.Y', $postID); ?></title>
```

Here is get_the_date() function on [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_date).

Comment: I used Yoast Seo plugin and It supports a function %%month%% but it will output in format Jan, Feb...could you please help me to output as format in number 1,2,3...12

Comment: As I wrote, in get_the_date() function is parameter $format. If you type 'n', you get month in number format. Everything is on WP codex. Btw if you need to set month to all URL, you can do it in WP admin panel -> settings -> permalinks and here choose custom structure. Here you can make structure  as you want. If you want use month of post in every url, you type %monthnum% there. Here is good article for you http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/seo-friendly-url-structure-for-wordpress/ (look at section 'Creating custom URL structure with available tags). I hope this helps.